# Create ko.observableArray from JSON object in Knockout JS

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have JSON object loaded to my view model. I want to push that into an observableArray.

```
function viewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.details = [{"id":1,"first_name":"fname1","last_name":"lname1","salary":1000.0},
                    {"id":2,"first_name":"fname2","last_name":"lname2","salary":2000.0},
                    {"id":3,"first_name":"fname3","last_name":"lname3","salary":3000.0}];

    self.emp = ko.observableArray([new Model(self.details[0]),new Model(self.details[1]),new Model(self.details[2])]);
    
    //This method works, but is very inefficient... 

}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

The solution I found was to feed each element individually, which is not practical.

I'm using JQuery. I found some solutions using knockout.mapping plugin. But I'm unable to add that plugin to my Eclipse workspace correctly.

I'm new to Knockout. Please help me find a solution to add the entire object to the observableArray.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the mapping plugin personally, but this should also work

```
function viewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.details = [{"id":1,"first_name":"fname1","last_name":"lname1","salary":1000.0},
                    {"id":2,"first_name":"fname2","last_name":"lname2","salary":2000.0},
                    {"id":3,"first_name":"fname3","last_name":"lname3","salary":3000.0}];
                    
    var mapped = self.details.map(m => new Model(m));
    //or
    //var mapped = self.details.map(function(m) {return new Model(m);});
    
    self.emp = ko.observableArray(mapped);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```